# How do I make Kile work with TeX Live 2012?

Tags: latex, kile

Since I was not happy about the choice of texlive 2009 from Ubuntu repositories, I installed texlive 2012 manually from the website.

Secondly, I like Kile to write, but when I try to install it, it forces me to install all the packages that i want to avoid (2009 version). So I used equivs and made a dummy Ubuntu package that tricks the OS (Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit) into installing kile without those packages.

The problem is that Kile refuses to compile.

When I try to do it, from the output I can see that he does:

- cd into the right directory
- executes the pdflatex command

And that's it. The funny thing is that repeating the same exact command via the terminal, the file is compiled correctly (I updated correctly the PATH, after all).

Any ideas on how can I get it to work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had updated the PATH only via .bashrc. With a rapid check of "Settings > Check System" it showed up that he did not know where to look for the binaries.

I solved by adding `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux` to `/etc/environment`